# How to insert '_' as htmlAttributes in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is probably a simple question, but to which I havent found an answer yet.

How to escape the ' _ ' when creating an HtmlElement in razor?

To render a '-' in the final Html we put an ' _ ', but to render an '_' (underscore), How do we escape it? I tryed '@:', but it didn't work, and didn't find any other options...

Example:

```
 @Html.CheckBox("Access_Groups", false, new
                   {
                       @class = "input-control checkbox",
                       @data_group = "I', looking for data-group",
                       @Description_pt = "<----- I'm looking for Description_pt"
                   })
```

@data_group will render as data-group as expected, but...
@Description_pt will render as Description-pt, and that is not what is expected (don't know how to escape the _ for this)
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [signature of `Html.Checkbox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492737%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), we can see that it takes an object for the `htmlAttributes`.  Further, looking at the syntax, its actually a key based collection of objects.  A `Dictionary<string,object>` fits that bill and allows you to absolutely specify the name of the html attributes that you want to add (note each key is typed exactly how we want it to display).

```
@Html.CheckBox("Access_Groups", false, new Dictionary<string,object>
{{"class", "input-control checkbox"},
{"data-group", "I', looking for data-group"}, 
{"Description_pt", "SomeValue"}})
```

This renders the following HTML

```
    <input Description_pt="SomeValue" class="input-control checkbox"
data-group="I&#39;, looking for data-group" id="Access_Groups" 
name="Access_Groups" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

Comment: Nice one, still havent tried, but it looks very promissing...will do it today. Thx you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the HTML character code for underscore, i.e., `&#95;`?